# bash save values in variable

Tags: bash, shell

given: file: files.txt with:

```
sara.gap sara.gao
pe.gap pe.gao
```

I just want to use f=sara in my bash skript, because I need f later in the skript. so i tryed: get ffirst line,second argument,remove .gao and save in f

```
f=sed -ne '1p' files.txt |cut -d " " -f2 |sed 's/.gao//g'
```

But did not work, please help me ;(

Comment: Don't get me wrong but you should work on your english, it's really hard to undertand what you said. At least try some spell checker

Comment: `sed 1q file` will be more efficient than `sed -n 1p file` because it will exit after the first line, while the latter must read the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

You just need backticks:

```
f=`head -1 files.txt | cut -d " " -f2 | sed 's/.gao//g'`
```

Comment: Thank but the I have in f the hole command , not the map string (here) sara??

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your comment. Could you try to rephrase?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do

```
read f junk < files.txt
f=${f%*.gap}
```

oh, and for second argument:

```
read junk f junk < files.txt
f=${f%*.gao}
```

That's completely in bash :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Command Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) if you want to use the output of a command to set a variable. The format is `v=$(command)`. You can also use backticks e.g. `` v=`command` ``, but this has been superseded by the `$(...)` form.

Your command would be:

```
f=$(sed -ne '1p' files.txt |cut -d " " -f2 |sed 's/.gao//g')
echo $f
```

prints

```
sara
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
f="sed -ne '1p' files.txt |cut -d ' ' -f2 |sed 's/.gao//g'"
eval "$f"
```

with output:

```
sara
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` as well

```
f=$(awk 'NR==1{gsub(/\.gao/,"",$2);print $2;exit}' file)
```